# Integer type ambiguity for int64_t

Tags: c++, gcc

```
 #include <stdint.h>
 class Something { ...
  void put(int32_t value, int32_t scale = 0);
  void put(int64_t value, int32_t scale = 0);
  void put(bool value);
 };
```

a calls to `something.put(4LL)` is ambiguous. How is int64_t defined so that it is not a perfect match for long long int constant, which is what the error message tells me it is?

Comment: Maybe `int64_t` is `long`.

Comment: Just taking a guess here, but 4LL is still 4 and 4 will fit in both a 32bit or 64bit integer...could be wrong though

Comment: @Thomas: What's relevant for overload resolution is the type, not the value. `4LL`, `4L`, and `4` all have the same mathematical value, but they're all of different types.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ok that makes sense, like I said wasn't sure. Haven't done any hard core C++ coding in a while. I need to go and get a c++11 book hah alot has changed

Comment: I expected this to be a duplicate, and, indeed, it was; I just couldn't find it for myself.

Answer (score 2):

`int64_t` is a typedef (i.e., an alias) for some predefined type.  It could be `long long int`, or `long int`, or even `int` if type `int` happens to be 64 bits.

Overload resolution is based on the type of the argument, not its value or its size. Even if `long long` and `int64_t` have exactly the same size and representation (as they very likely do), they're still distinct types. `4LL` is of type `long long`; that *may or may not* be the same type as `int64_t`.

If you want to call `put()` with an `int64_t` value of `4`, you'll need to ensure that your argument is of the right type. For example:

```
const int64_t arg = 4;
put(arg);
```

or

```
put(int64_t(4));
```